# Firebase functions config is truncating my api key string

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set an environment variable in firebase functions like this:

```
firebase functions:config:set clientsecret="abc123$efgh"
```

However, when I use:

```
firebase functions:config:get
```

I am seeing all of my settings, but it looks like my `clientsecret` value is getting truncated after the `$` character.

```
{
    "myservice": {
        "clientid: "1234567"
        "clientsecret": "abc123"
     }
}
```

Is there a way I should be escaping or encoding the `$` so the entire string is stored? Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't with Firebase or Cloud Functions.  The problem is the $ character.  That's a special shell character that takes the letters after it and assumes it's a shell variable.  So, your command is telling the shell that you want to insert the value of variable `efgh` into the command line.  Since that variable is probably not defined, you're getting an empty string in its place.  So, `$efgh` is yielding an empty string.

If you want to use $ in a shell command line like this, you're going to have to escape it.  There is [a lot to know about this](https://www.shellscript.sh/escape.html).  Maybe the easiest thing is to simply escape the $ itself with a backslash:

```
firebase functions:config:set clientsecret="abc123\$efgh"
```

Comment: Thank you! I just found that I needed the `\` to escape it.

Comment: Or if you happen to be on Windows you can just use the Command Prompt.